# How to avoid cascading animation (@keyframe) on children in css?

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation

Do you know how I can avoid that children divs do not animate with the parent?

```css
@keyframes rotate
{
 from {
  transform: rotate(0deg)
 }
 to {
  transform: rotate(360deg)
 }
}

.gradient {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(#ff0000, #0000ff);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
}

.gradientitem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -15px; 
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <div class="gradientitem" style="transform: rotate(180deg) translate(100px) rotate(180deg);"></div>
  <div class="gradientitem" style="transform: rotate(0deg) translate(100px) rotate(-0deg);"></div>
</div>
```

So here you can see an example of my problem that the two little circles are rotating with the big circle. I tried different things like changing the position or "animation: none" for the children...

Comment: where should the little circles sit if they weren't rotating with the parent circle?

Comment: fixed on their postition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new element for the animation inside gradient div

```
<div class="gradient_animation"></div>
```

add animation css to this class. it works.!

```css
@keyframes rotate
{
 from {
  transform: rotate(0deg)
 }
 to {
  transform: rotate(360deg)
 }
}

.gradient {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
  position: relative;
margin: 100px;
}

.gradient_animation{
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(#ff0000, #0000ff);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
}

.gradientitem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -15px; 
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
<div class="gradient_animation"></div>
  <div class="gradientitem" style="transform: rotate(180deg) translate(100px) rotate(180deg);"></div>
  <div class="gradientitem" style="transform: rotate(0deg) translate(100px) rotate(-0deg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're welcome! don't worry.. it's all about helping each other :)